# Plus 2 date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I really need help on this those function DATEDIFF OR DateAdd , because I have no idea on those things.

```
Declare @EstDate as Date,
        @Shipdate as Date,
        @Workingday as Int,
```

I need to do like this:

```
@EstDate(Date) = @ShipDate(DATE) - @WorkingDay(int) - 2days
```

Example: @EstDate(date) = '6/11/2011' - 5days - 2days.

How can I do this formula in SQL ? >_< In PHP its easy, but in SQL 2000 up, I have no ideas.

Comment: To get real "working days" you need to make a calendar table to account for holidays and such.

Comment: I just need a query. To calculate Estdate like that. I have everything on table already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do it. Basically this adds a negative number of days to @ShipDate. The negative number of days will equal @WorkingDay + 2.

I really don't know what @WorkingDay is supposed to represent. This example assumes it's just a number that represents something to you.

```
@EstDate = DateAdd(dd,-(@WorkingDay + 2),@ShipDate)
```

It would look something like this, given your example:

```
@EstDate(date) = DateAdd(dd, -(5 days + 2 days), '6/11/2011')
```

Comment: wrong bro, Estdate must be less than ShipDate , if do your query, the EstDate is greater than ShipDate...